# I don't understand why my test if failing for a 3x nested resource index page. Help please

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a forums/topics/post model relationship that I am trying to test out for the index page.

Here is my test:

```
test "index" do
  get forum_topic_posts_path
  assert_response :success
end
```

This is my url from rake routes:

[image]

Here is where my test is failing:

```
PostsControllerTest#test_index:
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"posts"} missing required keys: [:forum_id, :topic_id]
```

This is my index action for my posts controller:

```
def index
  @posts = Forum.find(params[:forum_id]).topics.posts
end
```

What seems to be the problem here? I have specified where to search for the posts through the Forum.find(params) options and the topic_id should be included in that query. Although I have to admit this does seem cumbersome to write and I feel as if there is a better way to do this,I can't think of any other way. Can someone help me pinpoint where the problem is? Do I need to specify a particular topic parameter as well?

I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the required ids from the GET request. You need have a forum and a topic to reference in order for the path to work. The last part of the error message gives the hint as to what's wrong: "missing required keys". The test should look more like the below, although you may need to add the required attributes to create a forum and topic.

```
test "GET #index" do
  forum = Forum.create
  topic = forum.topics.create

  get forum_topic_posts_path(forum.id,topic.id)
  assert_response :success
end
```

A couple additional thoughts: You do need to reference the topic id in your controller action in order to get the posts. Your index action isn't quite to convention. Triple nesting could be a bit of a flag for a refactoring that should happen somewhere in your code (depending on the context, which I admittedly don't know). The below action should get you to a 200 success based on the test above.

```
def index
  @forum = Forum.find params[:forum_id].to_s
  @topic = @forum.topics.find params[:topic_id].to_s
  @posts = @topic.posts
end
```